# Trouble starting g-wan webserver on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: g-wan

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64bit, Intel® Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 2, 4.0 GiB.

I downloaded G-WAN from http://gwan.ch/download today. unzipped the file (version unzipped : G-WAN 7.12.6 64-bit (Feb  8 2016 16:33:28) ) and went to the directory.

But when I gave the command

I am getting the following error...

```
    #sudo ./gwan <enter>

    loading
    can't find '' Qspupdpm!Iboemfs!


    To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Qspupdpm!Iboemfs!
```

Just in case I also deleted the existing PID file and restated (new PID was auto generated). Then also it gave the above error.

Below is the output from log/gwan.log

```
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] G-WAN 7.12.6 64-bit (Feb  8 2016 16:33:28)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] /home/varshesh/numero/gwan/gwan
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] local time: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 18:40:20 GMT+5
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] last system reboot: 2023-01-13 09:14
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] RAM: (222.10 MiB free + 424.54 MiB shared + 46.54 MiB buffers) / 3.70 GiB total
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] physical pages: 222.10 MiB / 3.70 GiB
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] disk: 22.75 GiB free / 54.75 GiB total
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs  375M  2.3M  373M   1% /run
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  /dev/sda2      ext4    62G   23G   37G  39% /
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs  1.9G  112M  1.8G   6% /dev/shm
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  /dev/sda1      vfat    93M  5.3M   88M   6% /boot/efi
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  /dev/sda3      ext4    55G   32G   20G  62% /home
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs  375M  152K  375M   1% /run/user/1000
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] 922 processes, including pid:99976 './gwan'
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] page-size:4,096 child-max:14,684 stream-max:16
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] CPU: 1x Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  0 id: 0     0
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  1 id: 1     1
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] Cores: possible:0-3 present:0-1 online:0-1 
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] L1d cache:   24K line:64     0
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] L1i cache:   32K line:64     0
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] L2  cache: 4096K line:64   0-1
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] NUMA node #1 0-1
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] CPU(s):1, Core(s)/CPU:1, Thread(s)/Core:2
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] bogomips: 2,188.80 (per physical CPU Core)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] virtualization: VT-x
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]   using   1 workers 0[01]0
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]   among   2 threads 0[11]1
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] 64-bit little-endian (least significant byte first)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] Ubuntu 22.04 LTS \n \l (5.18.2-051802) 64-bit
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] user: root (uid:0), group: root (uid:0)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] backlog: 4,096
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] epoll_fds: 836,852
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] port range: 4096-65500
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] system  fd_max: 1,024
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] program fd_max: 1,024
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] updated fd_max: 1,048,576
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] virt max: -1, stack:8.00 MiB
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] nic: hw nic: 00:0c.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 06)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  wlo2: driver: iwlwifi
    wlo2: version: 5.18.2-051802-generic
    wlo2: bus-info: 0000:00:0c.0

    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] nic: ip addresses (2)
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  127.0.0.1
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT]  192.168.0.112
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] gcc version 11.3.0
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] minify:n caches: query_char:? default_lang:ANSI C
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] memory footprint: 3.18 MiB
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] host 0.0.0.0:8081_PONG
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] can't find '' Qspupdpm!Iboemfs!
    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] 
    To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Qspupdpm!Iboemfs!



    [Tue Jan 17 13:10:20 2023 GMT] exit(1): 
    To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Qspupdpm!Iboemfs!
```

I did read somewhere that getting this installed on Debian / Ubuntu is a challenge unlike CentOS.

Have been searching Stack Overflow, but nothing specific to this issue. Including the suggested links before posting this question.

Long back I downloaded the bash script for installing other plugin, and after that it was working then. Now the link to bash script is redirecting to expired domain.

Any guidance or help will be appreciated to get this up and going. Hope I have followed the format of this forum.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Guesses here but likely to be the cause of your trouble.

Your Linux distribution does not let G-WAN compile its scripts either because:

1. the compilation/linking fails (unfortunately you can't do much on this - but a future public version of G-WAN is in the works and that's a point worth addressing);
2. the system /temporary directory is not found or reachable - that's where the scripts are compiled. The G-WAN website documents the following:

G-WAN could not use the /tmp directory to store temporary compilation files. The most likely reason is that the 'x' (execute) bit has been disabled for security reasons. The workaround is either to:

```
use a more relaxed policy for the /tmp directory (so G-WAN can use it)
or
define an alternate /tmp directory (usable for the account running G-WAN) with: 
export TMPDIR=/.../temp
```

Note: the "..." above is the placeholder for a directory that you must create.

### Hope it helps.

[UPDATE]

This issue appeared for me today under **MICROSOFT Windows WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux)**. The offending script is the PONG "Protocol Handler" and ditching it resolved the issue.

So, once in the gwan directory (where the gwan executable is), type:

```
rm -rf "0.0.0.0:8081_PONG"
```

...and restart G-WAN:

```
./gwan
```

Comment: Thank you so Much Gil for replying,
The below is the directory setting of /tmp , on my Ubuntu 22.04

drwxrwxrwt  24 root root      24576 Oct 10 21:57 tmp/ 

Do I need to change 't' (sticky bit) to 'x' ? What will be the security implications ? 
and where do we give "export TMPDIR=/.../temp" as I am running the "./gwan" in the following directory "/home/varshesh/numero/gwan/gwan" 

'# ./gwan ... any thing after this ? ... Thank you

Comment: rm -rf "0.0.0.0:8081_PONG"   - see my answer below (this comment is here to let you see you got a reply).

Comment: Thank you very Much Gill ... Yes it worked!!! :) ... closing this issue ....